# List element not being counted?

Tags: python

I have a list in which I am trying to find the count of the last element's last character. I had it working, and then it stopped. I am not sure why. `self.hand[-1][-1]` returns `'h'`, which the `count` should return `5`. However, I am not getting `5`, I return `0`.

`poker_hand.py`

```
class PokerHand:
    def __init__(self, hand):
        self.hand = hand
        self.flush = False

    def is_flush(self):
        if self.hand.count(self.hand[-1][-1]) == 5:
            self.flush = True
```

`main.py`

```
from poker_hand import PokerHand, test_hand_one, test_hand_two

test_hand_one = ['Jh', 'Qh', 'Kh', 'Ah', '10h']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hand_one = PokerHand(test_hand_one)
    hand_one.is_flush()
    print(hand_one.flush)
```

current output: `False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the hand in your example,

`self.hand[-1][-1]` is the last character in the string in the final position of the list, which is `h`.

So this line is evaluating `self.hand.count('h')`, i.e. you are asking "how many times does `'h'` appear in `self.hand`?". It appears zero times (because `Jh` is not equal to `h`, `Qh` is not equal to `h`, etc.).

You need to ask "how many elements in `self.hand` have `h` in the final position?"

One way you could do this is with a list comprehension. The code will probably be clearer if you split into two lines.

```
last_card_suit = self.hand[-1][-1]
if len([card for card in self.hand if card[-1] == last_card_suit]) == 5:
    ...
```

Another way would be to get the suits of all the cards, then check that there is only one unique element using `set`.

```
suits = [card[-1] for card in self.hand]
if len(set(suits)) == 1:
    ...
```

Comment: This one gets the answer for being able to determine the count without hard coding any string values.

Answer (score 1):

`count` does not count the partial match. It's only counts the full match. ie, You are currently doing this,

```
>>> ['Jh', 'Qh', 'Kh', 'Ah', '10h'].count('h')
0
```

which will return `0` since none of the elements exactly match with the `count` argument.

You could either use the approach mentioned by @j1-lee in the comments Or you could use `sum` with generator expression.

```
>>> sum(1 for i in ['Jh', 'Qh', 'Kh', 'Ah', '10h'] if i[-1] == 'h')
5
```

Comment: How did it work before, though? That's what is confusing. I was getting the results I expected, and then it stopped.

Comment: @NicholasCrook Are you sure that you were using `['Jh', 'Qh', 'Kh', 'Ah', '10h']` in `test_hand_one`?

Comment: Yes, I did nothing to change the function. I only added a second test hand that the first stopped returning 5. I did nothing to delimit the 'h' from any of the elements. The flush function was the first function written in my exercise. I even tested by changing the last 'h' to a 's', and then back. It still worked until I added the second test hand.